# Hiss sound when I get output from the Voice Assistance AI

Tags: python, openai-api

I'm working on a Python script that utilizes the OpenAI and Eleven Labs APIs to convert text to speech and have a conversation with the GPT-3.5 Turbo model. The script allows users to input text and receive AI-generated responses as both text and audio output.

The code I'm trying to share includes the following functionality:

Integration with Eleven Labs API: The convert_text_to_speech function takes a text input, sends a request to the Eleven Labs text-to-speech API, and retrieves the generated audio as a stream. The audio data is then converted to a numpy array.

Integration with OpenAI API: The chat_with_model function interacts with the OpenAI GPT-3.5 Turbo model to generate AI responses based on user input. It sets up a chat-based conversation by passing previous messages and the user's input to the model.

Playing the audio: The script uses the simpleaudio library to play the audio generated from the AI response.

```
import openai
import requests
import simpleaudio as sa
import numpy as np

openai.api_key = "**********"
elevenlabs_api_key = "*************"

def convert_text_to_speech(text):
    url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/21m00Tcm4TlvDq8ikWAM/stream"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "audio/mpeg",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "xi-api-key": elevenlabs_api_key
    }
    data = {
        "text": text,
        "model_id": "eleven_monolingual_v1",
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.5,
            "similarity_boost": 0.5
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()

    audio_data = response.content

    # Convert audio data to numpy array
    audio_array = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.uint8)

    return audio_array

# Set up the ChatGPT model
def chat_with_model(user_input):
    model = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": user_input}
        ]
    )
    response = model.choices[0].message.content
    return response

# Main conversation loop
while True:
    user_input = input("User: ")

    # Generate AI response
    ai_response = chat_with_model(user_input)

    # Convert AI response to speech
    audio_array = convert_text_to_speech(ai_response)

    # Play the audio using simpleaudio
    play_obj = sa.play_buffer(audio_array, 1, 2, 44100)
    play_obj.wait_done()
```

Comment: sounds like you accidentally installed catGPT

Comment: Ha ha.. Lol . That's a good one